# ar() in R and Matlab give different results for same dataset

Tags: r, matlab, autoregressive

I have a Matlab script that performs some autoregressions and am trying to replicate it in R, but can't get them to match.

So as a MWE, I'm trying to get the same results in R as are obtained by [this example in the Matlab docs](https://www.mathworks.com/help/ident/ref/ar.html#mw_b9a02b99-e994-4653-89d6-3416a27bde2a):

```matlab
load iddata9 z9
sys = ar(z9,4)

% sys =
% Discrete-time AR model: A(z)y(t) = e(t)                            
%   A(z) = 1 - 0.8369 z^-1 - 0.4744 z^-2 - 0.06621 z^-3 + 0.4857 z^-4
%                                                                    
% Sample time: 0.0039062 seconds
%   
% Parameterization:
%    Polynomial orders:   na=4
%    Number of free coefficients: 4
%    Use "polydata", "getpvec", "getcov" for parameters and their uncertainties.

% Status:                                                
% Estimated using AR ('fb/now') on time domain data "z9".
% Fit to estimation data: 79.38%                         
% FPE: 0.5189, MSE: 0.5108
```

So, as I understand it, `sys` is an autoregressive model of order 4 based on  the `z9` timeseries.

Now, in order to replicate this in R, I'll need the `z9` timeseries. I'll also need to find the appropriate function to call (`ar()`, `ar.ols()`, `ar.mle()`, `ar.yw()` or `ar.burg()`).

According to the [Matlab docs](https://www.mathworks.com/help/ident/ref/ar.html#description):

> `sys = ar(y,n)` estimates the parameters of an AR `idpoly` model `sys` of order `n` using a least-squares method.

From this I conclude the best R function to use is `ar.ols()` (least squares method).

Unlike the Matlab function `ar()`, `ar.ols()` by default determines the best model order via AIC. I'll have to disable that, thereby forcing the use of a model of order `order.max`:

```r
z9 <-c(-0.78169732436269102, 4.2163489081188299, 8.3991425701037699, 12.3905782437681, 15.3017178972351, 17.5265414794188, 20.374451682603102, 19.860011961463801, 19.707656723336999, 18.890021696201199, 16.138707749128599, 14.103243742975501, 12.124169438212601, 8.9703828015333205, 4.9555659895425901, 2.8158800013430101, -0.96000196329166199, -3.8204986387165101, -6.4934611606999297, -9.0985645508532205, -11.5794949793918, -12.0987811836858, -13.6957180649972, -13.382169159841601, -13.0994179184617, -12.5463961952129, -12.3537955952199, -10.1105787443311, -9.2056372978981695, -6.5194934153247104, -4.20078270867391, -1.45307152281272, -1.0057723596955199, 2.6409248175226701, 4.2014838167328099, 6.0713940731081397, 7.35489377956607, 8.9245144939930992, 9.45396167761516, 9.6330395785713492, 9.6140799143354592, 9.7322733062332105, 8.8465247882219398, 8.0150059636162503, 6.26125054185552, 4.4448017895641296, 2.2850369374924901, 1.32183630207826, -0.63381135755833595, -1.9061892746534601, -2.95355098729042, -4.8058487422563996, -5.7329307815986796, -6.2984402414167002, -6.4762053521273497, -5.7162178901589504, -7.0723585312711403, -5.6339447369817002, -5.8700079655668604, -4.5904346815493398, -4.1373565790684799, -3.4477711422730901, -2.2463556654140402, -0.53443652348652404, 0.72239022447067103, 1.6337083414339, 1.85958511411488, 2.3747524807928202, 3.9560404066991501, 4.5893933460558998, 3.45344440663255, 4.9094359560814, 5.93306473016822, 4.5850810034178497, 3.9713706924486698, 3.2457283472268399, 2.1706359204572001, 2.0616381858567498, 1.6275862489070201, 0.133402921806686, -0.084571065390345798, -0.604893543241802, -2.0039938785578002, -2.0660003808098, -2.5119888641047701, -3.1647572797919099, -2.3743471081968801, -4.0591515094039998, -3.2233215927878902, -3.6399634284061402, -3.24536027972671, -2.28092730456288, -1.4996475901528601, -1.4531994254749001, -0.34556301115639199, -0.91030905995151801, 0.26974374459165201, 0.35598289154861501, 0.72144001500320398, 0.20574711987099001, 2.25264158850048, 3.0799828933489799, 2.57358344692256, 3.0997237181389599, 2.43428549334811, 1.6906897752051799, 1.6846760627910899, 1.45796344105633, 2.0847720873453399, 0.91864947403734998, 0.797634845865134, -0.33585684918852399, -0.17828781217815901, -1.2962022409468099, -1.19439558880353, -0.77342565557786203, -0.54794061625841095, -1.3420077137667099, -1.6465700301780599, -1.19698292411254, -1.33855520217333, -2.8317663478342401, -2.3512251884831699, -1.6728078156675801, -1.4565781064968399, -1.55748031626882, -0.81915331568836502, -0.66419009279650398, 0.62678941981035596, 0.031468336341288899, -0.065573230231712895, 0.56939036551418898, 0.60345199613562295, 1.2043488796592601, 1.04092005345169, 0.45159159084886902, 1.47684399949219, 0.95316403177807996, 0.74278514973356702, 0.488267100247333, 1.15197219185981, 0.51781607965112197, -0.40274844453201902, 1.25282280863386, -0.208819879234134, -0.098758612257166395, -0.23643541849636099, -1.2231715657588, -0.086375027451099498, -0.66534200041952496, -0.77749030754810899, -0.19608055860179299, -0.77842842317553096, -1.6725033529209199, -0.74319491970390095, -0.050537864805743099, 0.092953309434721396, -0.246652278221832, -1.0836457267741799, 0.45522300087265699, 0.0185150432879902, 0.274645961200707, 0.937771890509697, 0.60030639182323298, -1.37981067874803, -0.28958839067592601, 0.166739210348372, -0.0493062744571066, 0.66621297012920799, 0.63726678897759004, 0.16698007845024301, 1.03333084926331, -0.024666861171374701, 0.106379277629647, -0.15203427098987099, -0.367566879869832, 0.0074371055609401401, -0.81318798017594895, -0.36053375533968501, 0.133538773332392, 0.0619371792310911, -1.3653860121519901, -0.21909027092459099, -0.66366571172415301, -0.203946297920541, -0.320958064963353, -0.52774748628708701, -0.32614325788439602, 0.044954652159373401, 0.171825909654263, -0.493990050604241, -0.70963674456829895, -0.18410204378908901, 0.602319303837483, 0.32380182307224997, 0.40073434126110502, 0.023617459242779901, -0.107964482482869, 1.3316875477089201, 0.24715986897908601, 0.27830866710721403, 0.142616547049328, 0.28924251576306198, 0.0612530389535954, -0.34124201117827802, 0.38212998328463599, 0.80708659755626699, 0.129764739937864, -0.38414129202664798, -0.0309854710489481, 0.40776273652843198, 0.75143732336881397, -0.87378986266699898, -0.13749889451585201, -0.42611814018622701, 0.056535149089628298, -0.12895288893885801, -0.497118040833812, -1.08825982546337, -0.76709724111946698, -0.43328731483816002, -0.23317522568906099, 0.527622078681103, -0.32070688572769901, 0.19866422777953099, 0.49946161437242298, 0.192878938380871, 0.14550978774536399, -0.18132283180675801, 0.55969516581404, 0.96239994682048002, 0.388864903463567, 0.301914527909246, 0.25767352466038401, 0.64389452376323497, -0.055806798761705197, -0.16697953239805899, 0.33213014305603, -0.111420445029982, 0.46283488667789502, -0.73951036432601602, 0.63237391677356003, -0.41729243573991098, 0.048874292515301503, -0.31942129194285701, 0.26000457185224701, -0.81274801748473002, -0.64064578049395005, 0.71039035775398296, -0.588278016105654, -0.44086570758841198, -0.048416373891605601, -0.46419340258159197, 0.025193472369724398, 0.55769558166949995, 0.022417392282127802, 0.86921001151531097, -0.70172306503813997, -0.103793180119208, -0.38530048124978999, 0.24654942882174899, -0.56086339723128897, -0.80522236728471197, -0.120681882510209, -0.83291971555653899, -0.37872292002083102, -0.21006698511934199, -0.78044910043911897, 0.32621836736343701, 0.185401336135949, -0.29332679258948402, -0.68846562733324901, -0.14221497212199199, -0.10005627031034101, -1.1130730907923501, 0.61806962476396199, 0.174784001559569, -0.92519769865221302, 0.93719532548475903, -0.12996204340804901, -0.78917749953992999, -0.51284446145682006, 0.085978502812762495, -0.75926678415941695, -0.26885878778081601, -0.074602243908322804, -0.22749385103026501, 0.095901815822503705, -0.35298760357994002, -0.11376296208322, 0.114543040831869, -1.08424534059406, -0.92797160335670403, -0.49851636891871398, 0.077306019202830895, 0.139573527511685, -0.32810618971977201, 0.691531366077069, 0.59841097237659102, -0.061120850612385202, 1.68488008386997, -0.16645952114800899, 0.50163483797299102, -0.0279146984039941, -0.86501464708647902, 0.931524962853986, -0.54539302427422498, 0.018767274526705301, 0.93870233184836305, 0.29702042858393501, 0.15953404778312, -0.099256737817007307, 0.0964868461787739, 0.92036156702403005, -0.25293998776208498, -0.13021245051986099, -0.24360002950330001, -0.21774649645500899, -0.093586203926916703, 0.30657941084380302, 0.045671133510417003, -0.37460096024923301, 0.83554745301599198, -0.421929691277178, -0.14970312884966999, 0.0575149453307469, -0.82244344018558802, -0.48546363450831997, -0.62809505094820495, -1.31446761533712, 1.0824850056623101, -0.35143284579506101, 0.43110037946461599, 0.016687391231638302, -0.49213518353443397, -0.018462237866529601, 0.200984555665287, -0.57571811352352298, 0.59211597506533498, 0.58924176157708597, -0.059657876305430298, 0.29490677808086602, -0.62234521330382397, 0.27263851978799802, -0.077197642026890195, 0.79194931692252601, -0.48968379045343802, 0.99613832965598104, 0.0022540696172477798, 0.21701107266858299, 0.72120085983913196, 0.55013784483122996, -0.43708006571785901, -0.45469712522518502, -0.45260956723238399, 0.54379905055927102, -0.060111751118466297, -0.21365303154301499, 0.050553271577799402, 0.52738932165902597, -0.0701046880977991, 0.16346153794384599, -1.14972191112091, -0.32692546044498499, -0.52775920481585004, -0.31553492573053898, -0.37852284388921098, -0.21019963316977, -0.24638004741835201, 0.32668535177991898, 0.71453342566382405, -0.77215088389726805, 0.87089015100648803, 0.63534750974723597, 0.040261887666539001, 0.78337481355524097, 0.11585969945071201, -0.51627667617800099, 0.55836812664638202, 1.11146194789004, -0.39097080073490198, -0.50354610641962305, 0.56743751998149605, -0.0125906293029905, -0.68144306382477005, 0.61965676336444897, -0.074611431270262901, -0.39437833243831599, -0.286916493407329, -0.24448974525921199, 0.473344867649303, -0.57313222892603499, 0.239259126705891, 0.50659384082877001, -0.42595039818404901, 0.17061089780449101, -0.82397952303709798, 0.35045268730019102, -0.55988005151850595, 0.40360337088833198, 0.21641912063362301, -0.206800750686816, -0.74169766322151598, 0.66346415188086305, 0.073571257196196005, 0.835545579538158, 0.00098833967004349505, -0.89254223955884704, 0.84175876212567402, -0.14877233517487501, 0.45942691425209298, -0.36349700858323603, 0.30400902718270501, 0.41610586988753101, 0.50570405144280495, 0.24924242742941199, -0.0201440123129695, 0.073010700682865304, 0.152404046730718, -0.36760520661131701, 0.27715382203102101, -0.53006468141538299, -0.95037746187719596, 0.085640190750285797, 0.101177954728413, 0.112548910701415, 0.88839367357943499, 0.61813708782839205, 0.93326266490306597, 0.11117275202096, 0.45492302401441898, -0.29537927238455602, -0.11567509621641001, -0.87443761328286995, 0.034032216293585597, 0.46232360490762298, -0.53048074366183695, -0.11279743642704999, -0.36369130626983298, -0.40588241712651002, 0.449556572753878, 0.0320927885086668, 0.36840994462101401, 0.19720124414620599, 0.46694597622571299, -1.1292895244082699, -0.51147229244243597, -0.086073293513090302, 0.17409768877429599, 0.57461302729196495, -0.31918611045765399, -0.30165253945724901, -0.141600294612137, 0.34869999819079001, 0.054373851456593597, 0.56402759642507405, -0.384814119856207, 0.20665124043508501, 0.19457297741791299, -0.821163556092396, 0.14887003241418101, 0.87033872863406803, -0.59859575484225802, -0.31844228271025099, -0.50847484226853001, 0.56425540248662198, -0.27870017138872799, 0.375095069355801, -0.82307636156947594, -0.91205361494302495, 0.49785270578471102, 0.295814055622521, 0.13921706554681301, 0.48276354209244798, 0.033102554089321598, 0.069360195497965002, -0.43791962942865098, 0.0044111605439022998, -0.55036115307618805, -0.44541175466913302, -0.23854102730496199, 0.069570524525787603, 0.80173474625917995, 0.18917970564960501, 0.20356450249480701, 0.272187132967107, 0.60241355226128201, 0.29079805570400402, 0.032411148500829198, -0.21598122660434901, 0.29909646389082001, -0.84134202188172003, 0.0212003523072474, 0.47186419210432001, -0.11383116300844701, 0.28845558361228602, 0.086164611526444695, 0.29237296152986197, -0.24695640938351299, 0.835338553015048, 0.19795717215602199, 0.070116486536236602, -0.59571129172924397, -0.096993128244905899, -0.72321215254079496, -0.14467808943907801, -0.61491592556478603, -0.032278340356199302, 0.075867548921199499, -0.242442929345217, 0.81634874858142104, 0.68441810863512598)

ar.ols(ts(z9), aic = FALSE, order.max = 4)
#> Call:
#> ar.ols(x = ts(z9), aic = FALSE, order.max = 4)
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>       1        2        3        4  
#>  0.7923   0.4780   0.0921  -0.4698  
#> 
#> Intercept: -0.0245 (0.03169) 
#> 
#> Order selected 4  sigma^2 estimated as  0.5098
```

As we can see, the coefficients of the models are different. They are mostly similar in magnitude, but the differences are obviously far too large to be due to floating-point errors. Also, the signs are all switched: the man page for `ar.ols` says something about coefficient signs, but I admit I didn't understand it:

> For definiteness, note that the AR coefficients have the sign in
>
> `(x[t] - m) = a[0] + a[1]*(x[t-1] - m) + ... + a[p]*(x[t-p] - m) + e[t]`

I've tried basically every combination of every other `ar.*` function, adding the `demean` and `intercept` arguments, but couldn't get the results to match the Matlab output.

To be specific, running the code above with `intercept = FALSE` (which sets the intercept to zero, just in case Matlab does the same) barely changes the result:

```r
ar.ols(ts(z9), aic = FALSE, order.max = 4, intercept = FALSE)
#> Call:
#> ar.ols(x = ts(z9), aic = FALSE, order.max = 4, intercept = FALSE)
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>       1        2        3        4  
#>  0.7928   0.4777   0.0916  -0.4694  
#> 
#> Order selected 4  sigma^2 estimated as  0.5104
```

So it's not merely that Matlab assumes a zero intercept.

So, how can I get my R code to get the same output as that Matlab code?

Comment: What value does Matlab report for the intercept?

Comment: @whuber not sure, I don't actually have Matlab on my device (just the source code and output from the script I'm trying to replicate), so I just copied this example from the Matlab docs (linked above). In case Matlab assumes a zero intercept, I also ran the R code with `intercept = FALSE`: the coefficients are only slightly changed (fourth decimal place), nowhere near matching the Matlab output.

Comment: You say "only slightly changed," but now it looks to me like the agreement is excellent, apart from the difference in signs (which likely is a difference in conventions--consult the docs).  It would help to know the standard errors of these estimates reported by either one of the programs.  We could be looking at differences in targeted levels of floating point precision, for instance.

Comment: Have you tried creating lags and fitting those with lm()? You could do something like `lm(z9 ~ lag(z9)+lag(z9,2)+lag(z9,3)+lag(z9,4)` and compare that to `lm(z9 ~ lag(z9)+lag(z9,2)+lag(z9,3)+lag(z9,4)-1` to see if the intercept effect is as minor as your investigation (thus far) indicates. The roots of the Matlab vs R characteristic polynomials are very close, and all are outside the unit circle (so you're not trying to estimate something unstable). However, that is nothing close to conclusive. It is possible that Matlab, when inverting A, may introduce some numerical inaccuracy.

Comment: The Matlab function doesn't use plain conditional least squares like `ar.ols` does, it "Minimizes the sum of a least-squares criterion for a forward model, and the analogous criterion for a time-reversed model". `ar(z9, aic = FALSE, order.max = 4, method = "burg", demean = FALSE)` seems closest (with signs reversed), but most of the methods other than conditional OLS are closer to Matlab's version.

Comment: @whuber how do you see that? Each coefficient was changed by only around 0.0004 with `intercept = FALSE`, while the errors between the Matlab and R coefficients are each in the order of 0.03-0.04 (other than the second coefficient, which is much closer, though I assume that's a mere coincidence)

Comment: @ChrisHaug interesting. Do you know of any R function or package which more closely mimics how Matlab performs this calculation? If the answer is simply "R does it differently", then that's fine, but it makes for an easier migration if I can make these results match more closely.